# Extended initializer list for Qvector<qstring>

Tags: qt, vector, initializer-list

When I compile this code

```
QVector<QString> taskTitle({"Movies which are directed by Steven Spilberg",
                           "All those who have reviewed Gone whith the wind",
                           "Summation of Gone with the wind scores",
                           "All years which has a movie whith 5 or 4 scores increasingly sortd"});
```

compiler gives me:

```
error: no matching function for call to
   'QVector<QString>::QVector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

I also used:

```
QVector<QString> taskTitle={"Movies which are directed by Steven Spilberg",
                           "All those who have reviewed Gone whith the wind",
                           "Summation of Gone with the wind scores",
                           "All years which has a movie whith 5 or 4 scores increasingly sortd"};
```

and again:

```
error: in C++98 'taskTitle' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
```

my compiler is MinGW and came with QT 5.0.1
What can I do?

Comment: Do you have C++11 compatible compiler and appropriate compilation flag is set (-std=c++11)? What is version of Qt you have? Please update the question and add additional info about your build.

Comment: my compiler is MinGW and came with QT 5.0.1

Comment: If you use `qmake` is there `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` (or something similar) in your `.pro` file? Or if you don't can you attach you build script to question?

Comment: No all thing which are there are:   QT       += core

QT       -= gui
QT       +=sql

TARGET = Sqlite
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

Comment: @MrHsCE Do what fasked said, that's your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Possible solution

I think to enable C++11 features in MinGW you should set the appropriate flag. There is `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` to set compiler options for `qmake`. So your `.pro` file should look like:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
QT       += sql

# or c++0x
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

## Addition details

Also Qt has `Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS` macro to determine whether collections provide initializer-lists constructors or not. For example in `QVector`:

```
#ifdef Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS
#include <initializer_list>
#endif

template <typename T>
class QVector
{
    // ...

#ifdef Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS
     inline QVector(std::initializer_list<T> args);
#endif

    // ...
};
```

Based on this flag we can create a small application to test the feasibility of using a initializer list:

```
#ifdef Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS
    qDebug("Yes");
#else
    qDebug("No");
#endif
```

This flag is defined in `qcompilerdetection.h` file for Qt5 (`qglobal.h` for Qt4). For example for compiler I have (it is gcc 4.7.2) the following lines will enable C++11 features.

```
#if defined(Q_CC_GNU) && !defined(Q_CC_INTEL) && !defined(Q_CC_CLANG)
#  if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) || __cplusplus >= 201103L
#    if (__GNUC__ * 100 + __GNUC_MINOR__) >= 404
       /* C++11 features supported in GCC 4.4: */
#      define Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

So if problem isn't solved by setting `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` you can see into this file and explore which of flags are enabled for your compiler set.